# Router DHCP wireless vs. LAN entries, Internet Connectivity Issues

Tags: router, dhcp

I own a Linksys E1500 router. Given the DHCP client table below:

[image]

`COMPUTER` has a Wireless interface entry but no LAN interface entry. Does this mean the router does not detect `COMPUTER` to be physically connected via an Ethernet cable?

What could the problems be if the machine is actually physically connected to the router via an Ethernet cable? The outer plastic covering of my Ethernet cable is destroyed on one quarter of my cable and the wires inside are visible. Could this be a problem?

[image]

Comment: Yes, exposed pair wires could be a problem, why not try a different cable?

Comment: Gotta buy another 75-foot cable first. I just checked the connection ends and both are solidly plugged in. The exposed wires (which run for a quarter of the cable in the middle), aren't cut or anything, they're just exposed. Desk drawer must have rolled over the cable too many times.

Comment: if you turn off the wireless on COMPUTER, can it communicate with the router over the wire?

Comment: If I turn off the wireless, `COMPUTER` has no internet connectivity at all. Updated post with Windows Network Diagnostics info. Do those diagnostics results show a problem with my router or network configuration instead of my physical cable?

Comment: it shows that it failed to get an Ip from DHCP, even after a reset of the adapter.  You have some work to do my friend. Move the computer closer to the router, and try a different cable.  Perhaps spend some time reading up on the `ipconfig /renew` command.